# Deleting temporary url insecure logo link from Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ssl, url

I have a wordpress site that we recently made live. We built it with a temporary URL and then switched it to the live url. I'm getting a soft failure for the SSL because of the theme's default logo.png. I've done better search and replace to try and change it but it can't since it's hardcoded. How and where would I change that so that it shows the live url and is secured?

Website is hobnobevents.com

Error from whynopadlock.com: https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/828a837d-e8d4-4553-8492-5b1d7e784454

An image with an insecure url of "http://185.56.86.90/~onetoncr/hobnobevents.com/wp-content/themes/bodega/img/logo.png" was loaded on line: 1 of https://www.hobnobevents.com/.
Errors that are reported on line 1 are generally not part of the source code. This error may be caused by an external javascript file which is writing to the page, however we are unable to reliably detect these scripts in our automated test.
Please contact us using the "Need Help?" link below if you need assistance with resolving this error.

Comment: (probable) Reason being is that you most likely have something pointing to HTTP and is probably hard coded or in an included file. Should this be the case, simply use `//` instead of `http://` and it will self-propagate itself. You can use this method for pretty much anything.

Comment: Either what I said above, or there's something in DNS settings or your Wordpress settings that is causing havoc (cache/propagation issues), since I couldn't see any `http://` inside the HTML source of your site. Should this be "php" related, we won't be able to tell from rendered/parsed PHP directives. You could download the entire site on your PC and search for all files containing `http://`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Far easier: open the site in any browser having "Web Developer Extensions". It will show all network requests and hence can be used to spot the http:// ones, even if lurking in Javascript...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Ah ok, thanks. Yes, that does sound even faster.

Answer (score -1):

This File is Present in Your JavaScript.

URL of JavaScript
https://www.hobnobevents.com/wp-content/themes/bodega/js/default.min.js?ver=5.3.2

Code is
$j([theme_root+'img/logo.png']).preload()

Check this code or change the theme_root may help you.

Comment: Thank you for identifying it. What would you recommend I change the theme_root to so that it propagates the live url? Would it work to put https://hobnobevents... before the img/logo.png?

Comment: Yes change may help you. But if you change the domain in future you need to remember that change. So you can also remove this code i think this is not using in your website.